# Does an infinite collection of circles accumulates at a circle?

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, geometry, circles

There is an infinite collection of closed circles in the plane, all within a finite bounding square. Does it contain an infinite sequence of circles that converge to a circle?

Assume that a point is a circle of radius 0, and that convergence is defined by symmetric difference (i.e. the area of the symmetric difference between the sequence and the limit goes to 0).

I thought of the following proof:

- Represent each circle as a triple $(x,y,r)$.
- Since the collection is bounded, the $x$, $y$ and $r$ values of all circles are bounded.
- Therefore, there is an infinite sequence of triples $(x_i,y_i,r_i)$, that converges to a triple $(x_L,y_L,r_L)$.
- The limit triple represents a circle, and the symmetric difference between the circles in the sequence and the limit circle goes to 0.

My questions are:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. Is there another proof, that uses purely geometrical considerations (i.e. does not transform the circles to triples of numbers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct and in my opinion is the simplest way to prove this fact.

A more geometric approach is given by Hausdorff-Kuratowski convergence. The compactness theorem for such convergence says in particular that *any* sequence of compact sets (i.e. your circles) which are all contained in the same compact sets (the bounding square) converge, up to a subsequence, to some compact set.